# Во время теста containsExactlyInAnyOrder получаю NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

Это учебный проект, в контроллере метод, который возвращает список студентов найденных по возрасту. Пишу тест для этого метода `getStudentsByAge()` и при сравнивании коллекций получаю `NullPointerException`.

Класс `Student`

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "faculty_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Faculty faculty;

    public Student(Long id, String name, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Student(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Student(Long id, String name, int age, Faculty faculty) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.faculty = faculty;
    }

    public Student(){}
   
    //get and set

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Student student = (Student) o;
        return getAge() == student.getAge() && getId().equals(student.getId()) && getName().equals(student.getName());
    }
```

Класс `StudentController`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("student")
public class StudentController {

    private final StudentServiceImpl studentService;

    public StudentController(StudentServiceImpl studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Student> getStudentInfo(@PathVariable Long id){
        Student student = studentService.findStudent(id);
        if (student == null){
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(student);
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<Student> createStudent(@RequestBody Student student){
        Student addStudent = studentService.addStudent(student);
        return ResponseEntity.created(URI.create("")).body(addStudent);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/age", params = {"age"})
    public Collection<Student> getStudentsByAge(@RequestParam(value = "age") Integer age){
        return studentService.getStudentsByAge(age);
    }

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public Collection<Student> getAll(){
        return studentService.getAllStudents();
    }

    @GetMapping("/ages")
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Student>> getStudentsByAgeBetween(@RequestParam Integer min, @RequestParam Integer max){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(studentService.getStudentsByAgeBetween(min, max));
    }
}
```

Класс `SchoolApplicationTests`

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class SchoolApplicationTests {

    private String name = "Tom";
    private String name1 = "Piter";
    private String name2 = "Tod";
    private String name3 = "Monika";
    private String name4 = "Bob";

    private int age = 27;
    private int age18 = 18;
    private int age22 = 22;
    private int age28 = 28;
    private int age30 = 30;


    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Profile("dev")
    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public Server h2Server() throws SQLException {
        return Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9092");
    }

    @Test
    public void createStudentTest(){
        Student student = givenStudentWith(name, age);

        ResponseEntity<Student> response = whenSendingCreateStudentRequest(student);
        thenStudentHasBeenCreated(response);
    }

    @Test
    public void getStudentInfoTest(){
        Student student = givenStudentWith(name, age);

        ResponseEntity<Student> createResponse = whenSendingCreateStudentRequest(student);
        thenStudentHasBeenCreated(createResponse);

        Student createStudent = createResponse.getBody();
        assert createStudent != null;
        thenStudentWithIdHasBeenFound(createStudent.getId(), createStudent);
    }

    @Test
    public void getStudentsByAge(){
        Student student18 = givenStudentWith(name1, age18);
        Student student22 = givenStudentWith(name2, age22);
        Student student28 = givenStudentWith(name3, age28);
        Student student30 = givenStudentWith(name4, age30);

        whenSendingCreateStudentRequest(student18);
        whenSendingCreateStudentRequest(student22);
        whenSendingCreateStudentRequest(student28);
        whenSendingCreateStudentRequest(student30);

        MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        queryParams.add("age", "28");
        thenStudentsFoundByCriteria(queryParams, student28);
    }

    private ResponseEntity<Student> whenSendingCreateStudentRequest(Student student){
        URI uri = URI.create(getUriBuilder().cloneBuilder().path("/add").toUriString());
        return restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, student, Student.class);
    }

    private void thenStudentHasBeenCreated(ResponseEntity<Student> response){
        Assertions.assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.CREATED);
        Assertions.assertThat(response.getBody()).isNotNull();
        Assertions.assertThat(response.getBody().getId()).isNotNull();
    }

    private void thenStudentWithIdHasBeenFound(Long studentId, Student student){
        URI uri = getUriBuilder().cloneBuilder().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(studentId).toUri();
        ResponseEntity<Student> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, Student.class);

        Assertions.assertThat(response.getBody()).isEqualTo(student);
        Assertions.assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    private void thenStudentsFoundByCriteria(MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams, Student... students){
        URI uri = getUriBuilder().cloneBuilder().path("/age").queryParams(queryParams).build().toUri();
        System.out.println("uri.toString() = " + uri);
        System.out.println("students = " + Arrays.toString(students));

        ResponseEntity<Collection<Student>> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                uri,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                null,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<Collection<Student>>() {
                });

        System.out.println("response = " + response);
        Assertions.assertThat(response.getBody()).isNotNull();
        Assertions.assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);

        Collection<Student> actualResult = response.getBody();
        System.out.println("actualResult = " + actualResult);
        resetIds(actualResult);
        System.out.println("actualResult = " + actualResult);
        Assertions.assertThat(actualResult).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(students);
    }

    private Student givenStudentWith(String name, int age){
        return new Student(name, age);
    }

    private void resetIds(Collection<Student> students){
        students.forEach(item -> item.setId(null));
    }

    private UriComponentsBuilder getUriBuilder(){
        return UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
                .scheme("http")
                .host("localhost")
                .port(port)
                .path("/student");
    }
}
```

Запускаю тест и он падает с ошибкой:

```
uri.toString() = http://localhost:52713/student/age?age=28
students = [Student[id=null, name='Monika', age=28]]
response = <200,[Student[id=3, name='Monika', age=28]],[Content-Type:"application/json", Transfer-Encoding:"chunked", Date:"Wed, 30 Mar 2022 13:09:39 GMT", Keep-Alive:"timeout=60", Connection:"keep-alive"]>
actualResult = [Student[id=3, name='Monika', age=28]]
actualResult = [Student[id=null, name='Monika', age=28]]

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ru.hogwarts.school.model.Student.equals(Student.java:79)
    at org.assertj.core.internal.StandardComparisonStrategy.areEqual(StandardComparisonStrategy.java:113)
    at org.assertj.core.internal.StandardComparisonStrategy.lambda$iterableContains$1(StandardComparisonStrategy.java:131)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$1MatchSink.accept(MatchOps.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1632)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:230)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:196)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.anyMatch(ReferencePipeline.java:528)
    at org.assertj.core.internal.StandardComparisonStrategy.iterableContains(StandardComparisonStrategy.java:131)
    at org.assertj.core.internal.Iterables.iterableContains(Iterables.java:358)
    at org.assertj.core.internal.Iterables.assertContainsExactlyInAnyOrder(Iterables.java:1360)
    at org.assertj.core.api.AbstractIterableAssert.containsExactlyInAnyOrderForProxy(AbstractIterableAssert.java:440)
    at org.assertj.core.api.AbstractIterableAssert.containsExactlyInAnyOrder(AbstractIterableAssert.java:433)
    at ru.hogwarts.school.SchoolApplicationTests.thenStudentsFoundByCriteria(SchoolApplicationTests.java:137)
    at ru.hogwarts.school.SchoolApplicationTests.getStudentsByAge(SchoolApplicationTests.java:90)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)

2022-03-30 16:09:40.511  INFO 17488 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-03-30 16:09:40.512  INFO 17488 --- [ionShutdownHook] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2022-03-30 16:09:40.524  INFO 17488 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-03-30 16:09:40.528  INFO 17488 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Ошибка `NullPointerException` возникает в методе `equals` класса `Student`. В `students` и `actualResult` лежат одинаковые студенты.  Помогите решить этот ребус

Comment: Думаю, проблема в `getId().equals(student.getId())`. Для объектов созданных в тесте с помощью конструктора `id == null`, потому вызов метода `equals` бросает исключение.

Comment: Наверно тестирующая система опровергла свои ожидания. Добавьте проверку полей так чтобы не возникало исключений.

Comment: Roman-Stop RU aggression in UA, даже не мог на это подумать, после изменения условия сравнения объектов на getId() == student.getId в методе equals, тест стал успешным.
Спасибо за решение этого вопроса !

Comment: Самое интересное, что если использовать метод для сравнения Objects.equals(id, student.id), то ошибка NullPointerException не падает и тест проходит успешно.